# Why is AsyncStateMachine created for synchronous methods?

Tags: c#, roslyn

Imagine the following code:

```cs
public async Task<int> AsyncMethod() {
    return 42;
}
```

I decompiled this code using [SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgDABFAjAVgNwFgBQWoGYEBMcAygIYC2ADgDYCmAwtaQM7NwDeWc3C+UAHAgBsAHgCWAOwAuAPjgBBZgE8JAYwCytKQAsA9sAAUASg5ce5qAHY4AFgIZM5gL5YnQA===) and noticed that an *AsyncStateMachine* gets created.

But why is this the case for a method lacking an await operator? In my understanding, this method can only run synchronously and the compiler notices the absence of await, so why does the compiler not optimize this?

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/3659

Comment: Well, consider what is the point might be of having to use the async keyword when the compiler can trivially detect await in the method body.  You found out.  It does matter a lot, parsing method signatures happens very early, the bodies come later.  With the very nice benefit that you can arbitrarily arrange methods, they don't have to be declared before being called.  That github issue is not likely to be implemented.